Running together VS code and Oracle Reports Builder 12c on Windows
I have Reports Builder installed on my machine, which requires having JAVA_HOME (jdk 1.8).
Also, for the sake of building projects developed by VS Code, I have appropriate JAVA_HOME which points toward appropriate jdk (jdk-17.0.9).
When have both path in JAVA_HOME, during the execution of: mvn package, I got an error:

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
correctly,  this environment variable is needed to run this program.

How to make get rid off this problem? Thanks in advance.
This is how JAVA_HOME variable looks like:

And this is my PATH variable:

